# I try to get the latest git tag but doesn't work

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops

I am try to get the last tag from other branch.
I have two branches "develop" and "release".

So I use this code to get the last tag:

```
#from release branch
git describe develop
```

on my desktop this show the version

```
V1.0.0.13-CC
```

my git version is:

```
git version 2.17.1
```

Ok. So my problem is the next:
I am use Azure devops and one pipeline with an inline powershell that do this:

```
$tagversion = $(git describe develop)
Write-Host  'Version Git: ' $tagversion
```

this show an error with this message:

```
##[error]fatal: Not a valid object name develop
```

Te repository is the same with 2 branches but I not know what is the problem.
The azure git version is git version 2.18.0.windows.1

Somebody can help me?
Is there any other way to do the same?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The error message implies that the targeted repo has no `develop` branch. Are you sure you're targeting the right repo? As an aside: you don't need `$(...)` around the `git` call, and you should generally avoid `Write-Host` unless your intent is to print to the _screen_. Therefore: `$tagversion = git describe develop; "Version Git: $tagversion"`

Comment: Usually, CI systems try to be efficient in terms of working with the source code. If a build is triggered for a `release` branch, it will be the only local branch checked out in that local clone on the build agent. That said, the command `git describe some-other-branch` won't find that branch name. What if you try to change it to `git describe origin/develop` instead of just `develop`?

Comment: Yes!, the two are right. Azure devops not know the develop branch but origin/develop run ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Yan Sklyarenko Since your solution is working. You can post your comment as answer. So it might help others who come across this issue.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Thanks for the hint, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, CI systems try to be efficient in terms of working with the source code. If a build is triggered for a `release` branch, it will be the only local branch checked out in that local clone on the build agent.

That said, the command `git describe some-other-branch` won't find that branch name. Try to change it to `git describe origin/develop` instead of just `develop` - it should work.